# How to export aimation based on IK with a non bone object as target?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes

I have setup a rigged character with bone chains having cylinder objects as their IK target, So far I can animate them by keyframing the cylinder transforms with I key (locRot keys). how do I export these animations?

Comment: To what format? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: fbx! I cant find the workflow on it.